# Flash crashing as VOIP client

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, voip

I have a web application with three states.

1. Dial in — (basically, none of the below)
2. VOIP — Connected to a Freeswitch instance
3. Listen — this option is through a normal connection to an FMS instance (different server from #2).

The initial state is chosen via a pop-up when the user first enters the application. From then on, these are all controlled by a ComboBox. When it changes, the application checks for all open connections and then closes them. It then opens the appropriate new connection.

The problem is that sometimes this causes the application to freeze for 10-20 seconds, and sometimes it causes it to crash and I have no idea why. `trace`s which should fire before the VOIP change only appear after the freeze (there will be a delay in the timestamps), but if I comment out the call to the change function, they appear in the order expected.

What is going on? Is this architecture simply not tenable? Is there a better way to do things?

Comment: Some questions: 1) is it a web app or AIR (or other)? 2) can you repro the crash if you just close all the connections repeatedly? Or just open a bunch of connections repeatedly? 3) Do you see any activity on the server (IE post connection) before the crash?

Comment: Think you need to just do what you can on both sides to get more logging information to see why it's crashing, check out the mm.cfg file (google it) you can get much more in depth function call logging on the AS3 side, on the server side "tail -f" whatever logs you can.  There's likely an error somewhere that'll help get you on the right path.

Comment: @shaunhusain One of my problems is that this problem shows up most in Chrome, which uses its own Flash player (and unfortunately, there is no way to prevent that without making users do annoying adjustments). Since mm.cfg only effects Flash debug player that means that using traditional `trace`s won't work.

Comment: @ethrbunny 1) Web. 2) Sometimes >:-[ ! 3) I have to admit I had neglected to think of that (I read your comment, my jaw dropped, and I thought, "That was such a rookie mistake... I can't believe I didn't think of that..."). I'll see what happens and get back.

Comment: @cwallenpoole hmm okay hear ya there. You may also be able to make use of ExternalInterface.call("console.log('something to trace')"); to get some trace info in Chrome, but that is unfortunate (also I wouldn't leave the logs in there like this long term probably good to do in a static function or something to make it quick to change out).

Comment: @ethrbunny Survey says... it was all a red herring (see answer below), but if it weren't for you pointing out the obvious I wouldn't have gotten it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently... the connections were a red herring.

After looking at the results on the server, it became apparent that the problem was with placing the call to the processing functions inside of a Flex generated EventListener. The previous developer used the `change="handler(event)"` property which was causing the crash. When I switched over to `<voip-drop-box>.addEventListener("change",function(e:Event):void{});`, everything cleared up instantly.